# UPDATE inner join query with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

i am trying to update two tables with one query using inner join but it's not updating or neither showing any error. here is the code

```
$id_prod = 2;
$id_cust = 2;
$sql5 = "UPDATE `customer` 
           INNER JOIN `products` ON products.cust_id=customer.id 
         SET prod_name = 'CAKE' AND name = 'Hassan' 
         WHERE id='$id_cust' AND id='id_prod' ";
$query5 = $conn->prepare($sql5);
$query5->execute(array($id_cust, $id_prod));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its generating an error BUT you are not looking for any errors. Add some error processing code after the prepare and execute or just add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the column to be set is misnamed, if you prefix the column name with the table name, is that better ?

*Like this :*

```
$id_prod = 2;
$id_cust = 2;
$sql5 = "UPDATE `customer` 
           INNER JOIN `products` ON products.cust_id=customer.id 
         SET __tableName__.prod_name = 'CAKE' AND __tableName__.name = 'Hassan' 
         WHERE __tableName__.id='$id_cust' AND __tableName__.id='id_prod' ";
$query5 = $conn->prepare($sql5);
$query5->execute(array($id_cust, $id_prod));
```

Comment: have you any message error ? (see: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly)

Comment: if you tape this : UPDATE `customer` 
           INNER JOIN `products` ON products.cust_id=customer.id 
         SET __tableName__.prod_name = 'CAKE' AND __tableName__.name = 'Hassan' 
         WHERE __tableName__.id='$id_cust' AND __tableName__.id='id_prod'  -- directly in phpmyadmin sql command textarea, what's happen ?

Comment: it is saying 0 row effected

Comment: What's your 'products' and 'customer' structure ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83864/discussion-between-nolwennig-and-mohsin).